# what is the correct process to use an R function to print the number of rows and columns in the dataset?

Tags: r

I need help with R on how to put this all in. I need help with the coding.

I tried to look it up and they have steps before that my program is saying error.

Comment: `dim()` will return the number of rows and columns in a data frame.

Comment: When i put it in it says error. could not find the function

Comment: When you run `dim(mtcars)` it gives you this error?